# Fabric.js disable object selection but enable target find?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to let all fabric canvas objects could be detected on mouse move, but cannot be click or select.

```js
if (isHoverMode == true) {
  canvas.selection = false
  canvas.skipTargetFind = true  // <-this cause object could be selectable!
  canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
      // do something on e.target ...
  });
}
```

It turns out that `canvas.skipTargetFind` must set to true in order to have `mouse:over` event to work. But then the objects could also be selected.

How could I prevent object to be selectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object property you're looking for is `selectable`.

Use it like this for a single object:

```
obj.set('selectable', false);
```

Or like this for all objects:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.selectable = false;
```

See http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#selectable